# Segmentation fault in if clause using gcc/ubuntu

Tags: python, c, gcc

I am writing a c-function for use in python. When run a segmentation fault occurs, which, according to printf calls, is thrown at an if-clause. The output to the shell is:

```
row 1, col 0: 1.000000
row:0, -col:0, index:0
-2: 0.000000
else
row:0, -col:1, index:1
-2: 0.000000
else
row:0, -col:2, index:2
-2: 0.000000
else
row:0, -col:3, index:3
-2: 0.000000
else
row:0, -col:4, index:4
-2: 0.000000
else
row:1, -col:0, index:5
-2: 1.000000
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

(the last line means segmentation fault)

and the c-code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define pi 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679

void hough(const void* img, int imgRowCount, int imgColCount, const void* thetas, int thetaCount, const void* rhos, int rhoCount, void* out)
{

  const double* imgD = (double*) img;
  double* outD = (double*)out;

  const double* thetasD = (double*)thetas;
  const double* rhosD = (double*)rhos;



  printf("row 1, col 0: %f\n", imgD[getIndex(1, 0, imgColCount)]);


  int row, col, thetaInd, rhoInd, index;
  double rhoVal, minDiff, diff, tmp;
  for(row = 0; row<imgRowCount; row++)
  {
      for(col = 0; col<imgColCount; col++)
      {
          printf("row:%d, -col:%d, index:%d\n", row, col, getIndex(row, col, imgColCount));
          tmp = imgD[getIndex(row, col, imgColCount)];
          printf("-2: %f\n", tmp);
          if (tmp>0.0)
          {
              printf("-1");
              for(thetaInd = 0; thetaInd<thetaCount; thetaInd++)
              {
                  rhoVal = col*cos(thetasD[thetaInd]*(pi/180)) + row*sin(thetasD[thetaInd]*(pi/180));
                  minDiff = INFINITY;
                  index = -1;
                  for(rhoInd = 0; rhoInd<rhoCount; rhoInd++)
                  {
                      diff = abs(rhoVal-rhosD[rhoInd]);
                      if(diff<minDiff)
                      {
                          minDiff = diff;
                          index = rhoInd;
                      }
                  }
                  if(index>=0)
                  {
                    printf("1\n");
                    outD[getIndex(index, thetaInd, thetaCount)] += 1;
                  }
              }
          }
          else
          {
            printf("else\n");
          }
      }

  }


}



int getIndex(int row, int col, int maxCol)
{
    return col + row*maxCol;
}
```

and at last the python code beeing used:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes
from scipy.misc import imread



def makeReady(arr):
  return np.require(arr, dtype=np.double, requirements=["C_CONTIGUOUS"])



def hough(imgBin, thetaRes=1, rhoRes=1):
  if len(imgBin.shape) > 2:
    imgBin = np.mean(imgBin, axis=2)

  if imgBin.max() > 1:
    imgBin /= imgBin.max()

  if ((imgBin!=0) * (imgBin!=1)).sum()>0:
    imgBin = imgBin > (imgBin.max()/2.0)

  nR,nC = imgBin.shape
  theta = np.linspace(-90.0, 90.0, np.ceil(180.0/thetaRes) + 1.0)
  D = np.sqrt((nR - 1)**2 + (nC - 1)**2)
  q = np.ceil(D/rhoRes)
  nrho = 2*q + 1
  rho = np.linspace(-q*rhoRes, q*rhoRes, nrho)
  H = np.zeros((len(rho), len(theta)))


  imgC = makeReady(imgBin)
  thetasC = makeReady(theta)
  rhosC = makeReady(rho)
  outC = makeReady(H)


  lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./hough.so")
  lib.hough(imgC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), imgC.shape[0], imgC.shape[1], thetasC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), len(thetasC), rhosC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p),outC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p))



if __name__ == "__main__":
  img = 1 - (imread("lines.jpeg"))>125
  print img.shape
  a = np.zeros((5,5))
  a[1,0] = 5
  hough(a)
```

what am i doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Where exactly in the code does it crash? Add a comment in the line.

Comment: Consider adding `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf` to get an accurate information on where the execution reaches.

Comment: Compile in debug (-g).  If using bash use `ulimit -c unlimited
`.  Run the program then find the place it is failing using the core dump and a debugger.

Comment: All of those casts are not necessary, and just add clutter.

Comment: Check return value from `getIndex`.  You nest calls inside `[ ]` in several places, you might be exceeding the array bounds.

Comment: You should try running your code in a debugging tool (like `valgrind`) to see exactly what the error is. Valgrind will even give you the line number the error occurs (if you compile with debug information -- `-g -O0` on gcc/clang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that looks like it could cause that error is going out-of-bounds on an array. Using the function `getIndex(...)` inside of `[]` could be causing your problem.

However, due to the difficulty to read the code (no comments, and no context), I recommend using a debugger (like `valgrind`) to give you information about the location of the error. In fact, `valgrind` will even print the line number the error occurs on, provided you compile with debug symbols (`-g -O0` on gcc and clang).

Comment: thank you, what a dumpy mistake -.-
is it possible to check within the c code for such a mistake and give a relevant expection?

Comment: Static analyser like [splint](http://www.splint.org/) or `gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic` *MIGHT* be helpful either.

Comment: what i meant was writing some lines of code at the beginning of the c-method to check, wether the needed arguments were given.
e.g: if(img not defined) throw Exception

Answer (score 0):

From the output the error seems to happen in this part of the code:

```
          for(thetaInd = 0; thetaInd<thetaCount; thetaInd++)
          {
              rhoVal = col*cos(thetasD[thetaInd]*(pi/180)) + row*sin(thetasD[thetaInd]*(pi/180));
              minDiff = INFINITY;
              index = -1;
              for(rhoInd = 0; rhoInd<rhoCount; rhoInd++)
              {
                  diff = abs(rhoVal-rhosD[rhoInd]);
                  if(diff<minDiff)
                  {
                      minDiff = diff;
                      index = rhoInd;
                  }
              }

              if(index>=0)
              {
                printf("1\n");
                outD[getIndex(index, thetaInd, thetaCount)] += 1;
              }
          }
```

A segmentation violation could only be caused here by accessing one of the three arrays (`thetasD` and `rhosD` and `outD`) out of their bounds.

This could only happend if the indices run to far, which in turn could only happen if the for-loops' break condtions are wrong, which could only happen if the wrong values had been passed to `hough`.

The latter indeed seems to be the case, as the Python script is missing to pass `rho`'s size and though is passing nothing for `outD`.

This line:

```
lib.hough(imgC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), imgC.shape[0], imgC.shape[1], 
  thetasC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), len(thetasC), 
  rhosC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), 
  outC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p))
```

should look like:

```
 lib.hough(imgC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), imgC.shape[0], imgC.shape[1],
   thetasC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), len(thetasC), 
   rhosC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p), len(rhosC), 
   outC.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p))
```